# Automatic margins when using css

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html, css

If i used CSS my div automatically margins left and right if i use inline style its works perfect,i don't understand whats going when i use CSS
i'm using React.js

I'm trying to style with CSS,its gives auto margin to left and right

```
<div className="container">
            <h1>hello</h1>
</div>
```

//CSS code

`.container 
    background-color: lightblue;
}`

//i'm using inline style its works perfect

```
``
<div style={{backgroundColor: 'blue'}}>
            <h1>hello</h1>          
</div>
``
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have included bootstrap in your project and container is a bootstrap class, so it adds style from bootstrap library as well
Try using any other class name it will just work fine.

Comment: i totally forget container is a bootstrap attribute,thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Please note, container is a bootstrap class, so it adds style from bootstrap library as and try using any other classes name it will be worked excellent.